# Deleting multiple files one after the other

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete two files, one after the other from directory in this way:

```
 protected void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pdfUrl = string.Empty;
    string imgUrl = string.Empty;
    SqlCommand sCmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT PDFUrl, ImgUrl FROM Book WHERE Id='{0}'", TextBoxDelete.Text.Trim()), con);
    con.Open();
    Object result = sCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    if (result != DBNull.Value)
    {
        pdfUrl = result.ToString();
        imgUrl = result.ToString();

        string fullPathPDF = Server.MapPath(pdfUrl);
        string fullPathImg = Server.MapPath(imgUrl);

        if (File.Exists(fullPathPDF))
        {
            File.Delete(fullPathPDF);
        }

        if (File.Exists(fullPathImg))
        {
            File.Delete(fullPathImg);
        }
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Book WHERE Id='" + TextBoxDelete.Text.ToString() + "'", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

But only the first file gets deleted. How can I delete both files - one after the other, because in this case only the `PDFUrl` gets deleted.

Comment: Actually, you are trying to delete two files one after the other. The answer depends on what is the result you are getting. If no exception is thrown, then the file does not exist at the time of checking. If an exception is thrown, well then, show us the exception.

Comment: Like Rotem said, nothing is "at the same time" you are simply deleting one after the other, and from your code, if you have both paths, both should be deleted.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to check the file exists before deleting it. If it doesn't exist, nothing happens.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski You just blew my mind!

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski not if the path is an empty string or just a path...

Comment: @Steve Yes, that's true. I was assuming you pass it a valid file path.

Comment: Well given the test for DBNull your assumption is safe....

Comment: Well, as you can see guys all my badges are related to Scholar and Student...so I can make mistakes and cannot be professional as you are. I think there are downvotes just because I wrote "deleting files at the same time", because there's nothing wrong with the code. Now I cannot post questions anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) cannot return two results.
It returns the first column of the first row so your imgUrl string is the same as the pdfUrl string.

You should change your code to use an SqlDataReader

```
protected void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pdfUrl = string.Empty;
    string imgUrl = string.Empty;

    // Using a parameterized query to avoid malicious user text that could wreak havoc....
    // Sql Injection is a serious problem. Always use a parameterized query......
    string cmdText = @"SELECT PDFUrl, ImgUrl FROM Book WHERE Id=@id";

    // Enclose disposable objects in a using statement 
    // DO NOT KEEP a global connection object... there is the connection pool
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....connectionstringhere....))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBoxDelete.Text.Trim());

        // ask the command to create a reader for us....
        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Check if a record is returned by the reader
            if(reader.Read())
            {
               // OK we could get it but not if it is DBNull.....
               pdfUrl = reader.IsDbNull(0) ? string.Empty : reader[0].ToString();
               imgUrl = reader.IsDbNull(1) ? string.Empty : reader[1].ToString();

               // Prepare the full path for the two files...
               string fullPathPDF = pdfUrl.Length > 0 ? Server.MapPath(pdfUrl) : string.Empty;
               string fullPathImg = imgUrl.Length > 0 ? Server.MapPath(imgUrl) : string.Empty;

               // Start deleting them
               if (File.Exists(fullPathPDF))
                   File.Delete(fullPathPDF);
               if (File.Exists(fullPathImg))
                   File.Delete(fullPathImg);

               // CLOSE THE READER BEFORE EXECUTING ANOTHER COMMAND
               // This could be removed if your connection string uses 
               // MultipleActiveResultSets=True   (MARS)
               reader.Close();

               // The parameter is still there, the command is still linked to the connection
               // Just change the commandtext and execute....
               cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Book WHERE Id=@id";
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```